# How does $J_{-n}(x)=(-1)^n J_{n}(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, solution-verification, bessel-functions

I am trying to understand why $J_{-n}(x)=(-1)^n J_{n}(x)$.

In the following link http://oer.physics.manchester.ac.uk/PDEs/Notes/jsmath/Notesse37.html the author proves this by doing the following

(*Edit*: there is a typo in the link. $\Gamma(-n+k+1)!$ should be corrected to $\Gamma(-n+k+1)$, without the factorial sign. This correction was made in the expressions below.)

The definition of $J_n(x)$

$$
{J}_{n}(x) ={ \mathop{∑
}}_{k=0}^{∞} {{(−1)}^{k}\over 
k!(n + k)!}{\left ({x\over 
2}\right )}^{n+2k}.
$$

The proof: $J_{-n}(x)=(-1)^n J_{n}(x)$

$$
\begin{eqnarray}{
J}_{−n}(x)& =& {\mathop{∑
}}_{k=0}^{∞} {{(−1)}^{k}\over 
k!Γ(−n + k + 1)}{\left ({x\over 
2}\right )}^{n+2k} %&
\\ 
& =& {\mathop{∑
}}_{k=n}^{∞} {{(−1)}^{k}\over 
k!Γ(−n + k + 1)}{\left ({x\over 
2}\right )}^{−n+2k}%&
\\ 
& =& {\mathop{∑
}}_{l=0}^{∞}{{(−1)}^{l+n}\over 
(l + n)!l!}{\left ({x\over 
2}\right )}^{n+2l} %&
\\ 
& =& {(−1)}^{n}{J}_{
n}(x). %&(10.41) \\ 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

There are two thing I don't understand about the proof. Could someone explain why

1. in the first line of the proof why is it $(\frac{x}{2})^{2k+n}$ not $(\frac{x}{2})^{2k-n}$.
2. Assuming the first line of the proof is right, why is it when the that we changed the lower limit of the sum from $k=0$ to $k=n$, $k! \Gamma(-n+k+1)$ remained unchanged.

Comment: For the 2), notice $1/\Gamma(x)$ is zero for any negative or zero integer $x$. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, OK thank you. What about (1).

Comment: I think that 1) is a typo and it should be $-n$ too. I it is just the substitution  $\nu=-n$ in the function of general real order.